# Extract matching fileds from dictonary

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

is there some smarter way to extract all keys from an OrderedDict into an new dictionary?

For example: I will collect all keys matching with 'pre' into the dict 'cfg_pre'. I tried this (it works):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import collections

dl=collections.OrderedDict()

dl ={ 
        'pre_enable': True, 
        'pre_path': '/usr/bin/pre_script.sh', 
        'pre_args': '-la -w --dir', 
        'post_enable': True, 
        'post_path': '/usr/bin/post_script.sh', 
        'fail_enable': True, 
        'fail_path': '/usr/bin/failure_script.sh', 
        'fail_args': '--debug 4'
        }

cfg_pre = dict((k,v) for k, v in dl.items() if 'pre' in k)
cfg_post= dict((k,v) for k, v in dl.items() if 'post' in k)
cfg_fail=dict((k,v) for k, v in dl.items() if 'fail' in k)


print (cfg_pre)
print ("---")
print(cfg_post)
print ("---")
print(cfg_fail)
print ("---")
```

The keys in the dl-dict always starts with pre, post or fail. 
Thanks ;)

Comment: Notice that after you re-assign to `dl`, it is no longer an OrderedDict.

Comment: What do you want your output to be? 3 dictionaries, 3 `OrderedDict`s? Something else?

Comment: I think your solution is already good. Don't see an alternative which is obviously better. ---- Might this be of help `print {x.split('_')[0] for x in dl.keys()}`? Will give `set(['pre', 'fail', 'post'])`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Jeah, this is only a striped down minimal example. Thank you! -- For fruther use I want 3 dicts. One with all the pre-stuff in it, one with all the error-stuff and so on.

Comment: You could use a dict comphrension, `{k:v for k, v in dl.items() if 'pre' in k}` Note, it *might* be quicker to write a loop as then you only need to iterate over the dictionary once rather than 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT -> Updated to fit your need**

If you would like to generalize, I would suggest going to group by methods. Something like :

```
import itertools as it

#define a function to split your universe (here the beginning of your keys)
def keyfunc(key):
    return key.split('_')[0]

#group by prefixes
groups = {k:list(g) for k,g in it.groupby(dl, keyfunc)}

#build your output
output = {g:[(key,dl[key]) for key in v] for g,v in groups.items()}
```

you will get the following output:

```
{'fail': [('fail_enable', True),
  ('fail_path', '/usr/bin/failure_script.sh'),
  ('fail_args', '--debug 4')],
 'post': [('post_enable', True), ('post_path', '/usr/bin/post_script.sh')],
 'pre': [('pre_enable', True),
  ('pre_path', '/usr/bin/pre_script.sh'),
  ('pre_args', '-la -w --dir')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that three lines is short enough for such a problem.

It would be a little cleaner with dict comprehensions:

```
cfg_pre = {k: v for k, v in dl.items() if 'pre' in k}
cfg_post = {k: v for k, v in dl.items() if 'post' in k}
cfg_fail = {k: v for k, v in dl.items() if 'fail' in k}
```

You could also remove the redundant data like this:

```
cfg_pre = {k.replace('pre_', ''): v for k, v in dl.items() if 'pre' in k}
cfg_post = {k.replace('post_', ''): v for k, v in dl.items() if 'post' in k}
cfg_fail = {k.replace('fail_', ''): v for k, v in dl.items() if 'fail' in k}
```

The dictionaries will be more consistent and the information about *pre*, *post* and *fail* will be stored only in the variable name:

```
cfg_pre = {'args': '-la -w --dir', 'enable': True, 'path': '/usr/bin/pre_script.sh'}
cfg_post = {'enable': True, 'path': '/usr/bin/post_script.sh'}
cfg_fail = {'args': '--debug 4', 'enable': True, 'path': '/usr/bin/failure_script.sh'}
```